# Which image formats are supported by Microsoft Word 2010 / 2011?

Tags: microsoft-word, images

As the title suggests:

Which image formats (raster and vector) are supported by Microsoft Word 2010 for Windows / 2011 for Mac? They should support the same formats but still.

I have not found this information elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the "Insert Picture" dialog we have:

- Windows Enhanced Metafile (*.emf)
- Windows Metafile (*.wmf)
- JPEG File Interchange Format(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jfif; *.jpe)
- Portable Network Graphics (*.png)
- Windows Bitmap (*.bmp; *.dib; *.rle; *.bmz)
- Graphics Interchange Format (*.gif; *.gfa)
- Compressed Windows Enhanced Metafile (*.emz)
- Compressed Windows Metafile (*.wmz)
- Compressed Macintosh PICT (*.pcz)
- Tag Image File Format (*.tif; *.tiff)
- Computer Graphics Metafile (*.cgm)
- Encapsulated Postscript (*.eps)
- Macintosh PICT (*.pct; *.pict)
- WordPerfect Graphics (*.wpg)

This is actually for Word 2007 on Windows (I misread the question) - but I can't see the list getting any shorter for Word 2010. Double check the Insert Picture dialog to make sure.

Comment: With what version on what platform?

Comment: @martineau - sorry, I'll update the answer

Comment: In case anyone is curious, Word 2016 has the list almost identical except the following were NOT included: *.bmz, *.gfa, *.cgm

Answer (score 2):

In Microsoft Word 2011, go to the Help menu and select Word Help. In the Help window search box, type "image file types" (without the quotes) and press return. In the list of topics at the left select the topic, "Graphics file types you can insert and save." Expand each topic that appears on the right and you will have a comprehensive list of the supported file types for Office 2011 (not just Word).

Answer (score 0):

Word/Mac can import all of the most popular graphics formats:

GIF
PNG
JPEG
TIFF
BMP
EPS
PICT
and more

http://word.mvps.org/faqs/drwgrphcs/graphicformats.htm

https://support.office.com/client/Graphic-file-types-you-can-insert-and-save-dad53574-3384-4ced-b472-348d37c326a7